# Norm of a bounded operator

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\phi \in C[0,1]$ and $T_{\phi}:C[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be: $T_{\phi}f = \int_0^1 f(x)\phi(x)dx$

prove that $T_{\phi}$ is a continuous, linear functional and that $||{T_{\phi}}|| = \int_0^1|\phi(x)|dx$

Here its what i've done. Its simple to show its linear, so i wont write that. And I have bounded the norm as:

$||T_\phi f|| = \int_0^1 f(x)\phi(x)dx \leq ||f||_{\infty}||\phi||_1$, so i know is continuous and bounded. $||T||\leq||\phi||_1$ But i cant seem to figure out how to show that they're equal.

I also have a tip: use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Comment: Do you know / are you allowed to know that $C([0,1])$ is dense in $L^1([0,1],dx)$?

Comment: i only know polynomials are dense in $C([0,1])$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first instinct is to let $f=\operatorname{sign} \phi$, because then $\int f\phi = \int |\phi| = \|f\|_\infty \|\phi\|_1$. But $\operatorname{sign} \phi$ is not continuous in general.

Instead, introduced the relaxed sign function: 
$$\operatorname{sign}_\epsilon x = \begin{cases} 1 \quad & x>\epsilon, \\ -1 \quad & x<-\epsilon, \\ x/\epsilon \quad & |x|\le \epsilon \end{cases}$$
The relaxed sign is continuous, and so is $\operatorname{sign}_\epsilon \phi$. By the dominated convergence theorem, 
$$\int (\operatorname{sign}_\epsilon \phi)\phi \to \int (\operatorname{sign} \phi)\phi = \|\phi\|_1$$
as $\epsilon\to 0$.

But maybe the dominated convergence theorem is not available. Then begin by picking a polynomial $P$  such that $\sup|P-\phi|<\delta$. The polynomial has finitely many zeros on $(0,1)$, which partition the interval into subintervals $I_j$. On each subinterval, let $f$ be a piecewise linear function with trapezoidal graph, so that $f=\operatorname{sign}P$ on most of the interval, and $f=0$ at the endpoints. This leads to an estimate of the form $\int fP \ge \int |P|-\epsilon\ge \int |\phi|-\epsilon-\delta$.